# How to hide a component in angular material mat-drawer if is closed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using mat-drawer but

what's the way to hide a component

if the sidebar is closed

like

```
<my-component *ngIf="isClosed"><my-component>
```

Comment: If you mean to hide it, than as you supposed: with `ngIf` directive. If you just want to close it, use `input` opened: `@Input()
opened: boolean` and set it to false

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is get the value from mat-drawer

Comment: Which value? Can you explain me more?

Comment: The value of input open if its true or false

Comment: You could call `ViewChild` if the `mat-drawer` is child component of `myComponent` and get the value. But to answer your question, you need to provide us with your code, or maybe the best and fastest way would be to make working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular